# Puppeteer - PDFPrint but pdf is blank

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a problem with puppeteer and pdf printing.

Everything looks ok, no error code,...  but pdf is blank.
and templateHtml is good ! maybe it's an error in functions call await ?

Please help me !

```
async function createPDF(quotation, quoteurl, quotname){

var templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), './templates/quotation2.html'), 'utf8');
//console.log(templateHtml);
var template = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
//console.log(template);
var html = template(quotation);
//console.log(html);



var pdfPath = path.join(`${quoteurl}`, `${quotname}.pdf`);
console.log(pdfPath)

var options = {
    width: '1230px',
    headerTemplate: "<p></p>",
    footerTemplate: "<p></p>",
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    margin: {
        top: "10px",
        bottom: "30px"
    },
    printBackground: true,
    path: pdfPath
}

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    //args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    headless: true
});

var page = await browser.newPage();
console.log('OH YES');
await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`,{ waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'load'] }).then(function (response) {
    //    page.emulateMedia('screen')
        page.pdf({ path: pdfPath
        , format: 'letter' })
          .then(function (res) {
            browser.close();
          }).catch(function (e) {
            browser.close();
          })
      })


}
```

i don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I Change with this content and it works ! but the logo.png doesn't appear in the pdf (or it's in the same folder than html file.

Is there something to add to puppeteer to include image file in the pdf ? (it's declared in html file)

```
await page.setContent(html,{ waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'load', "networkidle0"] }).then(function (response) {
    //    page.emulateMedia('screen')
        page.pdf({ path: pdfPath,
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,

            margin: {
              top: '20px',
              bottom: '20px',
              right: '20px',
              left: '20px' }})
          .then(function (res) {
            browser.close();
          }).catch(function (e) {
            browser.close();
          })
      })
```

Comment: You can try to debug the issue with an image by temporaily removing `page.pdf` from the script, launching puppeteer non-headless and using Devtools to review the DOM. Probably the image won't show because the HTML is set dynamically, not opened from a file, so the location of the image doesn't matter.

Comment: I modify the img to include a base64 image url, and it works :)

Comment: Nice! You should edit your answer to include that info and then accept your own answer!